# Unable to find Apple Paid Applications Agreement

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, apple-developer-account

I need to implement in-app purchases for my iOS application. For which I need to accept the Paid Applications Agreements but on the App Store Connect "Agreements, Tax and banking" page under agreements tab. I see no agreements. I have already accepted "**Apple Developer Program License Agreement**"and "**Apple Developer Agreement**".  I have attached the screenshot of my agreements page.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErNXO.png)

Most of the solutions I have seen online have a table at this page like so. but I see "There are no Agreements."

[I should see a table like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyYWK.png)

[Here's my apple developer homepage which says that I have accepted two agreements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCSE3.png)

I am signed-in as the account holder and admin of this account.

Comment: I think Apple don't publish that agreement until it's necessary. It should become available when you add an in-app purchase.

Comment: @lazarevzubov I have added 21 IAP's to my application but still unable to sign the contract.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to sign "Paid Applications" contract you need the following:

1. enable two-factor authentication for your account
2. Verify your legal
   entity information
3. Add bank Info
4. then you will be able to sign and
   accept the contract

Comment: Two-factor Authentication is enabled, Legal entity Status is clear, and a bank account has already been added.